# job and schedule in pgAdmin 9.3

Tags: postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3, database-backups, pgadmin

in my pgAdmin 9.3 don't exist the job or schedule for automatic backup !

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/database/how-to-install-pgagent-on-windows-postgresql-job-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

To get the jobs tag appearing in your pgAdmin, install [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html) by downloading the source code and then running `\i /path/to/pgAgent-3.4.0-Source/sql/pgagent.sql` in PSQL Console.
Then restart pgAdmin.